# Find indexes of the biggest and lowest numbers in array

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function which finds the two numbers with the largest difference between them and returns their indices as an array of two elements - `[ lowest, biggest ]`.

Notice: the bigger number must be to the right from lowest. If we have no difference between the numbers, the function must return `[]`.

```js
function getProfit(arr) {
    let result = [];
    let sortedArr = arr.sort();
    let min = sortedArr.indexOf(Math.min(...sortedArr));
    let max = sortedArr.indexOf(Math.max(...sortedArr));
    if(max > min) {
        result.push(min);
        result.push(max);
        return result;
    } else {
        return [];
    }

}

console.log(getProfit([13, 6, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3], [2, 4]));
```

Comment: What is your expected result? for `[2,4]`?

Comment: This is the array of indexes of the number with the biggest difference

Comment: `getProfit` take one parameter but you pass two prams? also when the array is sorted ascending first position is lowest and last position is biggest!

Comment: Why do you pass two arrays to the function? What's the expected result of the given code?

Comment: Also note that `By default, the sort method sorts elements alphabetically` so you need to sort numerically so use this one: `arr.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b;});`

Comment: Is `getProfit([13, 6, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3], [2, 4])` the unit test? Is `[2, 4]` the expected result of input `[13, 6, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Yes, this is unit test. Do I need to use assertion? [2, 4] is indexes of numbers with the biggest difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list with two pointers (indexes) `left` and `right` as described below:
you will accomplish your solution with time complexity of `O(n)`.

```js
function getProfit(arr) {
    let result = [0,0];
    for(let l=0,r=0; l<arr.length-1 && r<arr.length-1;r++){
        if(arr[l] > arr[r]){
            l++;
        }else if(arr[r]-arr[l]> arr[result[1]]-arr[result[0]]){
            result[0] = l;
            result[1] = r;
        }
    }
    return (result[1] === 0) ? [] : result;
}

console.log(getProfit([13, 6, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Wow... I tried to use the brute force with for() -> for()... I will remember it, thanks!

Comment: @RuddaTriduba The function `getProfit` need to have two arguments right?

Comment: @Nitheesh no, the function get one argument as input array and it must return another